# Props completion/auto-import don't work for Next.js WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frameworks, frontend, webstorm

I'm starting to use Next.js in WebStorm and I'm running into a big problem, Intellisense doesn't auto-import components and doesn't auto-complete the props of Next.js's own components. It's easy to replicate creating a Next.js app and open with WebStorm. The current version I have is the 2021.1.1.

I leave screenshots:

[image: no autocomplete props]

[image: no autocomplete component]

Comment: Tested and works fine in WebStorm 2021.3.1. Did you create it with `create-next-app@latest`?

Comment: Yes use that to create the application next. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
These steps helped me to solve the problem

1. Close the WebStorm
2. Delete the .idea folder manually
3. Reopen the project folder